# Mono friendly graphics libraries which are not dead

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, mono

I found this question [Intensive graphics application in C# (with .NET/Mono)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458976/intensive-graphics-application-in-c-with-net-mono) regarding graphics applications being Mono friendly quiet useful.  However, I also found that every answer that linked some project/solution I clicked on went to a dead project, or seemingly dead project.

Are there any graphics libraries for intensive graphics processing which are C# Mono friendly that are not abandoned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is definitely not dead. Also look at [Axiom](http://axiom3d.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which is Ogre engine ported to .net.

Answer (score 3):

What about [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28game_engine%29)? You have to pay for it but ...

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link, googling the project some revealed that it looks like they offer a free version.  Not sure the feature comparison between Unity and Unity Pro though.